# Static GCS Website bucket and http root domain not workiing

Tags: dns, google-cloud-storage, dnsimple

I created a GCS bucket `www.example.com` and have setup a CNAME record with my DNS provider (DNSimple) to point at `c.storage.googleapis.com`.  I can now access my domain with `www` but also want to make the root domain point at the bucket. Reading through threads on the same subject this seems to be possible with a synthetic record (google domains) or ALIAS record (other dns providers). I don't seem to be able to get this to work with DNSimple though so was wondering if anyone can spot my error?

I get the following error when accessing the root domain:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

I set my ALIAS record to point my root domain `example.com` at `www.example.com` but still no luck. So basically the below two records:

```
ALIAS   example.com www.example.com
CNAME   www.example.com c.storage.googleapis.com
```

Am I missing something or is this a limitation of DNSimple as this apparently seems to work with Google Domains (after reading through other questions)?

Just to add the bit from the Google documentation which states the same:

> Note: DNS does not support creating a CNAME record on a root domain,
> such as example.com, so in most cases, you must create your CNAME
> record on a subdomain, such as [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or myblog.example.com.
> Some DNS providers offer a non-standard feature that allows a root
> domain to be aliased to another name without the use of CNAME. Consult
> your DNS provider documentation to determine if such a feature is
> available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simpler than I thought. Instead of adding an ALIAS record I had to add an URL record pointing `example.com` at `http://www.example.com` to make the redirect work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not highly familiar with GCS, as I've used AWS for the same purpose. However, there's a few recommendations:

1. Make sure to [verify the domain](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website)
2. Make sure you have both the www and apex associated to the bucket/configuration. This is often the missing step. `www.example.com` and `example.com` are two different hostname, if you point both DNS records to Google but you configure only `www.example.com` in your Google Account, then the apex won't work (which may be your scenario).

Finally, I recommend you configure the ALIAS to point to the target (`c.storage.googleapis.com`) and not to the www local hostname.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Domain is verified and dns records are set as above so both the root domain and www subdomain should be pointing at the right bucket. Setting the ALIAS to point at c.storage.googleapis.com won't work as the bucket name is www.mydomain.com and they need to match for the DNS to resolve to the correct bucket.

Comment: The name is passed by the resolver. Pointing the ALIAS directly to the end name (and not to the www) is the way you should go as you will be cutting one resolution step.